# Flex desktop library project can't find mobile skin definitions

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, adobe, skin

I'm trying to make a Flex desktop library project and its complaining about lines
like these in my code:

import spark.skins.mobile.ButtonSkin;

I've tried importing all the SWC's which look relevant but I can't make these
compilation errors go away.

Importing the mobilecomponents.swc allowed me to get the LabelItemRenderer errors
to go away but not the skins.

Anyone know a solution ?  Or do I have to put any files referencing skins into the
top level application.

Yes. I know, ultimately I probably won't have mobile skins in my final library.  Just
trying to get it to compile for a desktop run at present and don't want to make thousands of changes to the code.

Thanks,

Shaun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been a while since I had to do this; but Mobile Skins are in a separate SWC than the mobile components.  In a library project, the skin SWC is not added.  At one point I think I even made a request in the Adobe Bug Base, but at this point I doubt it will ever get fixed.

I think the best solution is to manually add the mobile skin SWC to the class path.  It will be located at:

```
[Path to Flex4.6 SDK]\frameworks\themes\Mobile\mobile.swc
```

You may also be able to use the theme command line argument.  [I'm not sure if theme argument is available on library projects, though]

```
 -theme="[Path to Flex4.6 SDK]\frameworks\themes\Mobile\mobile.swc"
```

Comment: Awesome... yes, the skins swc is indeed hidden away in that themes directory.  The only place I didn't look. I added the swc to the library path and all the errors went away. Hope someone else finds this useful too.  Thanks again.